# How can I dynamically add text onto an image with HTML/Javascript/CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add text onto an image giving the text a transparent black background. Essentially, I want to achieve the effect described in the following link:

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CD8QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcss-tricks.com%2F3118-text-blocks-over-image%2F&rct=j&q=text%20on%20image&ei=IsmITsK4DYWc0AWj-4H9Dw&usg=AFQjCNHD2pL0MiEQObwT53pWzFq2gJoH6g&cad=rja

The problem is that I am dynamically generating these images and randomly placing them on the screen. Therefore, I cannot absolutely position the text (at least, not without knowing the height of the text in total). Is there another way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Surely you _can_ position the text seeing as it's inside the same container as the image, if you're using the code in that tutorial. I can't see what the problem is, but your question's pretty vague. We need to see markup, a demonstration or screenshots of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can position text absolutely. once images are loaded, even if randomly, jQuery's position() method will provide you will all the information you need.

obviously, you would like to to encapsulate images in containers e.g.  or use  and set image using div's background image. then you have all the freedom to put whatever text/effects you want in the container.

Comment: im trying to avoid putting the img as the background for i.e. compatibility reasons.

Comment: so then just go with <div><img></div> and use jQuery's append() and z-index to position text/other widgets above the image. remember that effects should be only relatively positioned to the container div.

Comment: I want to position the text along the bottom side of the photo, how do I know how far up to go?

Comment: Create a class for the text and set a fixed height, regardless of the length accross the width the height will be the same and you can make the calculations thusly.

Comment: if you want to add text along the bottom side of the photo, use relative positioning AND use right: 0px; bottom: 0px; that will help.

Answer (score 0):

> I am dynamically generating these images and randomly placing them on the screen.

Without seeing some of the code you have so far, it’s a bit difficult to help. If you’re dynamically generating the images, couldn’t you also dynamically generate the text along with it?

I.e. instead of generating:

```
<img style="position: absolute; top: RANDOMVALUE; left: RANDOMVALUE;">
```

Could you generate:

```
<div class="image-with-text-over-it" style="position: absolute; top: RANDOMVALUE; left: RANDOMVALUE;">
    <img>
    <p>Text to be overlaid on image</p>
</div>
```

And then in your stylesheet, write some CSS that positions the text in every instance of this over the image in that instance:

```
.image-with-text-over-it p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2em;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: rba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

Comment: yes, but that would place the text under the image, not on top

Comment: and by under i mean downward of, not underneath

Comment: @chacham15: well yes, but then you could use CSS to position the text relative to the enclosing `<div>`, so it would be on top of the picture.

Comment: if for whatever reason you don't like the above approach, an alternative would be to set the image to be the background of the element containing the text e.g. `<p style="background: url(dyanmicImage.png); height: height-of-image; width: width-of-image">some text</p>` and use padding to position the text. less elements required, but i think the above approach is altogether simpler!