# jQuery add Text to an Image placed in a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple table, say

```
<table id="table2" border="1">
        <tr>     
           <td id='id1' style="width:300px">some content</td> 
        </tr>

 </table>
```

And I am using jQuery to add an image to the cell like this:

```
$('#id1').append('<img src=images/image1 class=\'floatRight\' />');
```

the css style is like this:

```
  img.floatRight { float: right; }
```

Now after adding the image to the cell, I'd like to add some text, say "AAA", on top of the image, center aligned, how to I do that? Thanks

ps: by "on top", i mean "overlay"

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629142/how-can-i-dynamically-add-text-onto-an-image-with-html-javascript-css

Answer (score 0):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/SDtpS/

```
.floatRight {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}


.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    color: #ddd;
    font: bold 16px sans-serif;
}
```

JS

```
$('#id1').append('<div class="floatRight"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" /></div>');

$("#id1 div").append('<span class="text">Lorem Ipsum</span>');
```

Comment: the 2nd line should be a prepend if it's to go above the image hmm... and maybe `div` instead of `span`

Comment: @Rodolfo it doesn't matter because the `<span>` is absolutely positioned - http://jsfiddle.net/SDtpS/1/ And `span` seems to be more semantically correct to use if you want just a line of text

Comment: @Rodolfo - He want's it on the top of the image, not above the image. By on top I assume he means overlaying the image.